# How to build this query into laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this query

```
select est.*, bf.followup as bf_follow, bf.unidad as bf_unidad, bu.unidad as bu_unidad, bu.asistencia as bu_asistencia, bu.calificacion as bu_calificacion
from estudiantes as est
inner join bluecard as bc on bc.estudiante = est.usuario_id
inner join beneficiarios as bene on bene.usuario_creado = est.usuario_id
inner join (
    select bluecard, followup, unidad
    from bluecard_followups
    order by bf_id desc
) bf on (bf.bluecard = bc.bc_id)
left join (
    select bluecard, unidad, asistencia, calificacion 
    from bluecard_unidades
    order by bu_id desc
) bu on (bu.bluecard = bc.bc_id)

where bc.status = 1
group by est.usuario_id
limit 500
```

I know how to make joins with eloquent but that custom join i dont know how to write it.

Has something similar happened to anyone ?
Has anyone needed a query like this with laravel?

Help me out!
Thank you

EDIT

i run the query like this:

```
$estudiantes = Estudiantes::select(
                            DB::raw("
               select est.*, bene.contrato as nro_contrato, bf.followup as bf_follow, bf.unidad as bf_unidad, bu.unidad as bu_unidad, bu.asistencia as bu_asistencia, bu.calificacion as bu_calificacion
              from estudiantes as est
              inner join bluecard as bc on bc.estudiante = est.usuario_id
              inner join beneficiarios as bene on bene.usuario_creado = est.usuario_id
              inner join (
              select bluecard, followup, unidad
              from bluecard_followups
              order by bf_id desc
              ) bf on (bf.bluecard = bc.bc_id)
              left join (
              select bluecard, unidad, asistencia, calificacion
              from bluecard_unidades
              order by bu_id desc
              ) bu on (bu.bluecard = bc.bc_id)

              where bc.status = 1
              group by est.usuario_id
              limit 500"))
                    ->get();
```

and i got this error:

[image]

Comment: You're asking for a lot of code IMO.  You might need to use raw SQL for part of the Laravel query.

Comment: Is one way, but DB:raw does not retrieve de data as a collection and that it what i need

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about; Laravel allows you to use raw SQL in a Laravel query if needed.

Comment: could you, at least draw the relations between table..? also, have you actually tried the DB:raw and `dd` the result?

Comment: Use DB::select(your sql)

Comment: What models do you have? What relationships?  What have you tried?

Comment: I did use DB::select but i got an error

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't need a join but a [union](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#unions).
This way you just execute the current two join queries in seperate queries and than use the union function to apply them to the other query.